# AWS RDS Oracle: Synch Specific Schema to Test Environment

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

I want to sync data of specific Oracle Schemas, not ddl.

Both instances in AWS RDS.

Want to automate it to regularly Copy PROD to DEV. (once a month)

How to do it effectively?

Regards and thanks in advance.

Vincent

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow - your question is not suited to this StackExchange site as we focus of programmers and issues with their code, you are likely to find your question is a better fit on [sf]

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the size of the Oracle Schema you are referring. There are choices available according to that.

Oracle Data pump would be the ideal option to automate your requirements. There are details available in the link.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Regards,
Suraj

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).